# Understanding express async handler npm module code

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was trying to comprehend the code of express-async-handler

Which In their [Index.js](https://github.com/Abazhenov/express-async-handler/blob/master/index.js) is just 6 lines of code

```
const asyncUtil = fn =>
function asyncUtilWrap(...args) {
  const fnReturn = fn(...args)
  const next = args[args.length-1]
  return Promise.resolve(fnReturn).catch(next)
}

module.exports = asyncUtil
```

Now, I was trying to comprehend from it's usage that how does it work.

From their doc, it says

```
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler')

express.get('/', asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const bar = await foo.findAll();
    res.send(bar)
}))
```

But to my luck I am still not able to get that in the above example when are we passing the second argument i.e (correct me if I am wrong)

We are passing the code snippet below to `asyncUtil` which is going to be argument `fn`

```
async (req, res, next) => {
    const bar = await foo.findAll();
    res.send(bar)
}))
```

then

1. Question: **what** and **how** is our asyncUntilWrap gettingsomething
2. What is the use of spread operator inside `function(...args)`

Comment: The `asyncUntilWrap` function is passed to `express.get` and gets called by express as normally, just like when you are passing a callback to express without using `async-handler`.

Comment: @Bergi Can you please explain in slightly more detailed way?

Comment: @Bergi or in other words, what is being passed to `asyncUntilWrap`. talking about args in `asyncUtilWrap(...args)`

Comment: It gets passed whatever express passes to it when calling the `get` callback - usually that's `request`, `response` and `next`.

Comment: @Bergi Updated the question and post. If it isn't much to ask can you please go through it again.